# how to handle null in dynamic sql query

Tags: mysql, asp.net, t-sql, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to handle null varible in dynamic sql query

query is as follows

`DECLARE @_param_one VARCHAR(256)=NULL
DECLARE @_param_two VARCHAR(256)=''
DECLARE @SQLStr VARCHAR(MAX)`

the below select statement is working as expected if it is not converted as a string

`SELECT (SELECT CASE WHEN(COALESCE(@_param_one, '' ) = '') THEN 'WORKING' ELSE @_param_one  END) AS [Param_One]`

After converting to string and execute that string is not working as expected. The executed string is showing null.

`SET @SQLStr='SELECT DISTINCT 
           Column_One, 
           Column_Two,
           Column_Three
           (SELECT CASE WHEN(COALESCE( '''+@_param_one+''', '''' ) = '''') 
                THEN Param_One ELSE '''+@_param_one+'''  END) AS 
                [Param_One]
           FROM Table_One AS [![enter image description here][1]][1]Tbl WHERE Tbl.Id=2'`

`select @SQLStr`

[image]

Comment: check null before dynamic sql and make them blank string or any static string. also you can check which string is finally generated before execute by using Print function.

Comment: Setting null to empty before executing the dynamic sql query isn't working. @hasan mahmood

Comment: `IF @_param_one IS NULL 
 SET @_param_one = ''
SET @SQLStr='SELECT DISTINCT 
           Column_One, 
           Column_Two,
           Column_Three
           (SELECT CASE WHEN(COALESCE( '''+@_param_one+''', '''' ) = '''') 
                THEN Param_One ELSE '''+@_param_one+'''  END) AS 
                [Param_One]
           FROM Table_One AS [![enter image description here][1]][1]Tbl WHERE Tbl.Id=2'

print @SQLStr' now see what is wrong in this dynamic sql

Answer (score 1):

For this I would use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of a basic EXEC for your Dynamic SQL. First some simplified sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table_one','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table_one;
SELECT ID
INTO   #table_one
FROM   (VALUES (1),(2),(2),(3),(5)) AS x(ID);
```

The sp_executesql solution would look like this:

```
DECLARE @Param_One VARCHAR(512), @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

SET @sql = 
N'SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN COALESCE(@Param_one,'''') = ''''
                THEN ''<blank>'' ELSE @Param_one END
FROM #table_one AS t
WHERE t.id = 2;'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Param_One VARCHAR(256)', @Param_One = @Param_One;
```

Note that I'm returning the text, "blank" when your @param_one is blank of null -- I didn't understand your case statement. This code, however, should get you going. Feel free to respond with followup questions.

Answer (score 0):

Among many things wrong with above statement (e.g. SQL injection), null is a special case within SQL. Putting NULL as the word does not mean NULL in the SQL sense. You could add a bit of code to detect when NULL is the intended parameter and change the SQL statement accordingly.

In short, simply replacing the parameters as a string will not always work.

Comment: Not an expert with .NET but this looks like a step in the right direction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples

This is a similar problem in PHP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php